# How to group by multiple columns and order by date in SQL?

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, sql-order-by, window-functions

I would like to order results in a database table so they look like the following...

```
----------------------------------------------------------------------
Id                                   | Day | Start Date | End Date   |
----------------------------------------------------------------------
13D377E8-7674-4BE8-ACDF-472B634342D3 |  1  | 2019-11-26 | 2019-11-26 |
13D377E8-7674-4BE8-ACDF-472B634342D3 |  2  | 2019-11-27 | 2019-11-27 | 
13D377E8-7674-4BE8-ACDF-472B634342D3 |  3  | 2019-11-28 | 2019-11-28 |
78C8F3AD-DE5B-48BD-849A-6E39C7EC6200 |  1  | 2019-11-27 | 2019-11-27 |
78C8F3AD-DE5B-48BD-849A-6E39C7EC6200 |  2  | 2019-11-28 | 2019-11-28 |
78C8F3AD-DE5B-48BD-849A-6E39C7EC6200 |  3  | 2019-11-29 | 2019-11-29 |
B73ECD8B-5760-4F92-94E5-CF5270AEE36B |  1  | 2019-11-28 | 2019-11-28 |
B73ECD8B-5760-4F92-94E5-CF5270AEE36B |  2  | 2019-11-29 | 2019-11-29 |
B73ECD8B-5760-4F92-94E5-CF5270AEE36B |  3  | 2019-11-30 | 2019-11-30 |
```

- Each set of days is grouped by ID
- Days need to be shown from lowest to highest within the group
- The groups need to be ordered by the Start Date of the first day in each group ascending

I've tried just doing the following...

```
SELECT Id, Day, Start Date, End Date
FROM Table
GROUP BY Id, Day, Start Date, End Date
```

But predictably it doesn't order it correctly. You can see from the image below that a group that should appear first, by virtue of having the earliest start date, appears further down the list.

[image]

How can I solve this issue?

**Edit**

I attempted the solution below using the following SQL...

```
SELECT Id, Day, StartDate, EndDate FROM AssessmentCentreStandardAssessmentAvailabilityScheduleItemSchedule
WHERE AssessmentCentreStandardAssessmentAvailabilityScheduleItemId in 
(SELECT Id FROM AssessmentCentreStandardAssessmentAvailabilityScheduleItem
WHERE AssessmentCentreStandardAssessmentAvailabilityId = 
(SELECT Id FROM AssessmentCentreStandardAssessmentAvailability WHERE AssessmentCentreId = 
(SELECT Id FROM AssessmentCentre WHERE Name = 'Daily Assessment Centre')))
ORDER BY
    MIN(StartDate) OVER(PARTITION BY Id),
    Id,
    Day,
    StartDate
```

Note that I didn't include the where clause in my original post for brevity. I don't think it influences the result but posting just incase.

This returns the following....

[image]

It's not grouping by Id or Day, and simply appears to be ordering by Start Date ascending.

Just to reiterate the criteria visually incase it's unclear:

[image]

- I need records with the same Id grouped together.
- I need each day within the group of id's shown in ascending order (Note there are no duplicate day numbers associated with the same Id)
- I then need to order the overall groups by the Start Date of the first day in each group. There will be overlaps - so day 2's start date in group 1 will match day 1's start date in group 2, and so on.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To order groups by their minimumstart date, you can do a window `min()` in the `order by` clause:

```
SELECT Id, Day, Start_Date, End_Date
FROM Table
-- GROUP BY Id, Day, Start_Date, End_Date
ORDER BY
    MIN(Start_Date) OVER(PARTITION BY Id),
    Id,
    Day,
    Start_Date,
    End_date
```

Note: the fact that you are not using any aggregate function in the `SELECT` clause drives me to suspect that you don't actually need a `GROUP BY` clause. I commented that part of the query, feel free to add it back if, for some reason that I cannot think of, you do need it (if you just need to remove some duplicates, use `SELECT DISTINCT`, which makes the intent clearer).

**[Demo on DB Fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2017&fiddle=1d402a88a697926c1ae1c189c5a94a8f)**:

```
Id                                   | Day | Start_Date          | End_Date           
:----------------------------------- | --: | :------------------ | :------------------
13D377E8-7674-4BE8-ACDF-472B634342D3 |   1 | 26/11/2019 00:00:00 | 26/11/2019 00:00:00
13D377E8-7674-4BE8-ACDF-472B634342D3 |   2 | 27/11/2019 00:00:00 | 27/11/2019 00:00:00
13D377E8-7674-4BE8-ACDF-472B634342D3 |   3 | 28/11/2019 00:00:00 | 28/11/2019 00:00:00
78C8F3AD-DE5B-48BD-849A-6E39C7EC6200 |   1 | 27/11/2019 00:00:00 | 27/11/2019 00:00:00
78C8F3AD-DE5B-48BD-849A-6E39C7EC6200 |   2 | 28/11/2019 00:00:00 | 28/11/2019 00:00:00
78C8F3AD-DE5B-48BD-849A-6E39C7EC6200 |   3 | 29/11/2019 00:00:00 | 29/11/2019 00:00:00
B73ECD8B-5760-4F92-94E5-CF5270AEE36B |   1 | 28/11/2019 00:00:00 | 28/11/2019 00:00:00
B73ECD8B-5760-4F92-94E5-CF5270AEE36B |   2 | 29/11/2019 00:00:00 | 29/11/2019 00:00:00
B73ECD8B-5760-4F92-94E5-CF5270AEE36B |   3 | 30/11/2019 00:00:00 | 30/11/2019 00:00:00
```

Comment: Unfortunately this solution didn't work. I've detailed the response I got as an edit to my original post. Thanks

Comment: @Konzy262: this appears to work fine... I added a DB Fiddle to my answer for your reference.

Comment: My fault. In the actual table there are 2 id columns and I was referencing the wrong one. Works like a charm, cheers.